# Find out if a message fits into the 140 character limit of Twitter

Tags: php

I need to find out if a message fits into the 140 character limit of Twitter. 
This is what I have so far:

```
$tweetLength = strlen(utf8_decode($_POST["message"]));
if($tweetLength<141){
sendMessage();
}
```

Links get converted by Twitter into a t.co short URL.
How to check how many links are in the message and replace their length with the short-link counterparts?

> - a http:// link counts for 22 characters
> - a https:// link counts for 23 characters

Links can start with `http://www, https://www or www`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way would be to match all URLS in the tweet using a regular expression, and replace (`preg_replace`) it with a (dummy) 22 or 23 chars long string. Then you can get the character count.

In order to parse URLs the same way Twitter does, you can dig into the [Twitter Text for PHP lib](https://github.com/mzsanford/twitter-text-php) to see how it's really done.

Note that `strlen` won't work in many cases, since it will count special characters (accentued and others) multiple times because those are multi-byte chars. You need to use `mb_strlen` (the `mb_` stands for *multi-byte) to count that properly.

The developper guide gives [detailed insight](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/counting-characters) on how twitter counts chars under the hood:

> Tweet length is measured by the number of codepoints in the NFC normalized version of the text.

It even references PHP's [`Normalizer` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) to do that.

Comment: Also, have a look at [this post](http://blog.pay4tweet.com/2012/04/27/twitter-lifts-140-character-limit/) that shows how to do exactly that (but in JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
preg_match_all('/http:.*?com/', $message, $matches);

$message_length = strlen($message);

foreach ($matches as $match) {

    $message_length .= -strlen($match);
    $message_length .= 22;

}
```

You can handle the https case from here :)

Comment: Just want to add according to [twitter docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tco-link-wrapper/faq#How_long_are_t.co_links): `If you are not using the opt-in features, only links shorter in length than a t.co URL will be wrapped by t.co.`

Answer (score 0):

I would use :

```
$length= strlen(
    preg_replace(
        '/(?:http(s)?:\/\/|www\.)\S+/', 
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx$1', 
        $message
    )
);
```

This will replace :

- `http://www.stackoverflow.com` into `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- `https://www.stackoverflow.com` into `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs`
- `www.stackoverflow.com` into `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- `http://g.co` into `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- `https://g.co` into `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs`
- `www.g.co` into `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Then, your string has the final length, and you can easily check it :

```
if ($length <= 140) {
    sendMessage();
}
```