# how to get character's length which encoding with utf8mb4 in php and js

Tags: javascript, php, utf8mb4

I use mysql which support `utf8mb4` to store emoji, but in the php or js side, I can not get the correct length of them which is my function of textarea input maxlength.

as so far I know, utf8mb4 is not support by php or web side.
Does anybody know how to make it?

**i just get a js to solve it in js side ,which is supported by twitter!**
see [twitter-text-js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js)

but how to make it in php side, I don't find a new twitter-text-php?
I also find this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24039903/4431337), but how to use it?

Comment: Have you read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16893103/3424892)? You could do a `mysql_query ('SET NAMES utf8mb4')` before too... are you? The difference between UTF-8 and UTF8mb4 is that mysql "utf-8" does not support 4 byte characters, so they've corrected with UTF8mb4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using utf8mb4 with php and mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893035/using-utf8mb4-with-php-and-mysql)

Comment: i can get the correct char_length in mysql but how to make it in php before i store them in mysql?

Comment: You can get the character length of a UTF-8 string in PHP using `mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8')`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @ Austin yes,it my fault , php mb_* support utf8*,thk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- js 
  [twitter-text-js](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/js)

  `var tweet = "h饿1";
   var remainingCharacters = twttr.txt.getTweetLength(tweet);`
- php

  `mb_strlen`